# Is this a stutter?

Tags: traducción

In Cristina Henriquez' novel "*El Libro de Los Americanos Desconocidos*" (very interesting so far, by the way) there is this:

*"¿Que qué tal ha ido?"*

Is this double "que" redundant? Is it simply indicating that the speaker stuttered, or...?

google translate gives me for this, "they did it go?" - obviously not very helpful.

Comment: A bit more context could help to decide if it is a typo or it just lack an accent in the second "qué".

Comment: The second "que" does have an accent - I don't have the book with me at the moment, but my scribbled note shows an accent on the second "que" but not the first one...ok, I updated the sentence to show the accent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**ESPAÑOL - English follows**

Puede ser una frase correcta.

Persona 1 - ¿Qué tal me ha ido?
Persona 2- ¿Que qué tal te ha ido? Te ha ido mal, porque no lo intentaste lo suficiente.

Es una forma abreviada de preguntar:
Persona 2 - ¿En serio? ¿Me estás preguntando que "qué tal te ha ido"?

---

**ENGLISH**

It may be a correct sentence.

Person 1 - *¿Qué tal me ha ido?* (How did it go for me?)
Person 2- *¿Que qué tal te ha ido? Te ha ido mal, porque no lo intentaste lo suficiente.* (How did it go for you? It went bad, because you did not tried hard enough).

It is an abbreviated form of asking:
Person 2 - Really? Are you asking me that "how did it go for you"?

Comment: Clever; I reckon you're right.